# Can not Start an executable from C++

Tags: c++, python-3.x, flask

Python can start an executable file but not C++.

Python -

```
os.system('cmd /c "start FlaskServer.exe"')
```

C++ - (I tried 4 different versions)

```
system("cmd /c \"start FlaskServer.exe\"");
system("start FlaskServer.exe");
ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"cmd", L"/c \"start FlaskServer.exe\"", 0, 0);
ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"FlaskServer.exe", 0, 0, 0);
```

Note - The file I am trying to execute is a no GUI no console app(flask server) coded in python. It had no GUI I compiled it as GUI to avoid console. In python, it gets opened as a background process but in c++, not listed in the tasklist. Although, other programs with GUI are running fine.

Comment: You've had this issue for two months without getting it resolved? - I am not a python person, but I have to assume that there's something in the process search path, that FlaskServer.exe depends on, and which is there when you are launching from python both not from c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that being new to c++, I did not knew how to use Win32 buttons. I created WM_command with 2 button events, one for starting the application and other for killing it. I did not put "return 0" at the end. So, it first executed and the killed by the application.